# What does "a government vote" mean?

Tags: meaning

> ACTA bill approved by Japanese government in quick vote
>
> The bill despised by internet citizens around the globe, ACTA
>   (Anti-Counterfeiting Trade Agreement), has reared its ugly head once
>   more, getting passed in Japan after **a government vote** this week.
>   It was scheduled to be voted on early in the week, but due to delays
>   it was held on Thursday, September 6th, reportedly getting approved in
>   the wee hours of the night, with the news greeting Japanese citizens
>   and members of activist group Anonymous the next morning.

Answer (score 2):

[This source](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2203330/japan-ratifies-acta-agreement) tells us that the vote came in the Japanese House of Representatives, the lower and more powerful chamber of the National Diet. Both chambers vote on treaties, but the upper chamber can only delay ratification of a treaty approved by the lower.

Comment: Thank you, StoneyB.  Let me ask you one question.  Can I say that this is the same as "a parliamentary vote"?

Comment: @MountainShape That would probably make sense to UK readers; it might confuse some US readers who don't understand the difference between a parliament and our own Congress.